# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.product.context_processors'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm getting this error and I cannot find what is causing it. Here is the traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/passtur/apps/core/views.py", line 9, in frontpage
    return render(request, 'core/frontpage.html', {'newest_products': newest_products})
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 168, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 240, in bind_template
    processors = (template.engine.template_context_processors +
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 85, in template_context_processors
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 85, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "/Users/alex/projects/passtur/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.product.context_processors'
[27/Apr/2021 21:43:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 110467
```

My core/views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from apps.product.models import Product

def frontpage(request):
    newest_products = Product.objects.all()[0:8]

    return render(request, 'core/frontpage.html', {'newest_products': newest_products})

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'core/contact.html')
```

My context_processors.py is:

```
from apps.product.models import Category

def menu_categories(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    return {'menu_categories': categories}
```

Application directory structure is:

[image: main directory]

and details of core and product app folder structures:

[image: app folder details]

I should add that due to the tutorial I was following using an older version of Django (but not making that clear when setting up the project) I have had to make some changes to apps.py file as well to get it to find apps. I suspect this might be the cause of the problem but I cannot figure out how to solve it. My core/apps.py file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    #default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.core'
```

And product.apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductConfig(AppConfig):
    #default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.product'
```

I hope I have presented the info correctly and if anyone can help me with this specific issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `context_processors.py` should be at same level as `models.py` or `apps.py` not in `templates` folder

Answer (score 0):

`context_processors.py` should be at the same level as `models.py` or `apps.py` not in the templates folder